# Get field of optional object or return null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, option-type, nullable

I have optional object:

```
Optional<Detail> newestDetail;
```

I would like to return `newestDetail.getId()` or if `newestDetail` is null return `null`.

Do we have more sophisticated approach of doing this, than following?

```
return newestDetail.isPresent()?newestDetail.get().getId():null;
```

Comment: as a side note, there are *many* more convince methods inside `Optional`, see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBYhtvY19xA

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Map the value to an `Optional` with the id field and turn that one into a `null` value if it is empty:

```
return newestDetail.map(Detail::getId).orElse(null);
```