# Return null or new object using Optional object fields

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

We have a method, wherein we receive an `Optional<SomeType>` object. If the contained `SomeType` object is not null then we have to initialize a `SomeOtherType` object using the fields of the `SomeType` object and return that new object; otherwise we have to return null

We found multiple different solutions where we perform this task with two statements, first retrieving the optional object and then second creating the other type object e.g.

```
private SomeOtherType ourMethod() {
  SomeType someObject = getOptionalSomeTypeFromSomeWhere().orElse(null);
  return someObject != null ? new SomeOtherType(someObject.getField1(), someObject.getField2(), ...) : null;
}
```

Is it possible to cover this with one statement? So far we could not figure to do the null checks, accessing the fields, new object creation etc. all in one

Basically a more complex case of this question: [Get field of optional object or return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47714105/get-field-of-optional-object-or-return-null)

Comment: "We have a method, wherein we receive an Optional object, which might be null." Note that the `Optional` should never refer to a null reference : it defeats its purpose. Only the contained object could refer to `null`.

Comment: @davidxxx: Thanks for pointing this out. The concept was clear, but you are right that the phrasing was not good; changed it now

Comment: @davidxxx: Your comment was actually also useful to notice that I failed to escape the angle brackets, so only `Optional` was visible instead of `Optional<SomeType>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
return getOptionalSomeTypeFromSomeWhere()
    .map(someObject -> new SomeOtherType(someObject.getField1(), someObject.getField2(), ...)
    .orElse(null);
```